# Unable to set property of a single element in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In an array named admin, I want to show a div on the click of a button "update" when when I do so, the div shows below all the elements of the array. I only want it to show below the selected element.

```
function Admin(props) {
  const [showMe, setShowMe] = React.useState(false);

  const [updateName, setupdateName] = React.useState("");
  const [updateDesc, setupdateDesc] = React.useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="adminProducts">
        {props.admin.map((x, i) => (
          <div>
            {showMe ? (
              <div className="UpdateSection">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Product Name"
                  onChange={e => setupdateName(e.target.value)}
                  value={updateName}
                />
                <br />

                <textarea
                  placeholder="Product Description"
                  onChange={e => setupdateDesc(e.target.value)}
                  value={updateDesc}
                />

                <button
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={e => {
                    props.UpdateInfo({ updateName, updateDesc }, { x }, i);
                    setupdateName("");
                    setupdateDesc("");
                  }}
                >
                  Save
                </button>
              </div>
            ) : null}
            <div>{x.name}</div>
            <div>
              <button onClick={e => setShowMe(!showMe)}>
                {showMe ? "Close" : "Update"}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to set showMe as true for individual elements in array so that the div with classname UpdateSection only shows for that specific element and not for any other element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the id of the element you want to be shown:

```
  const [showMe, setShowMe] = React.useState([]);

  // ...

  const isShown = el => showMe.includes(el.id);

  const toggleShown = el => {
    setShowMe(shown => {
      if (shown.includes(el.id)) {
        return shown.filter(id => id !== el.id);
      }
      return [...shown, el.id];
    });
  };

  //...

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="adminProducts">
        {props.admin.map((x, i) => (
          <div>
            {isShown(x) ? (

            //...

            <div>
              <button onClick={e => toggleShown(x)}>
                {isShown(x) ? "Close" : "Update"}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Sorry, a part of code was missing, `showMe` has to be set as array on initial state.

Comment: This works but the button text which used to change earlier depending upon whether the div was hidden or shown doesn't work now.Can you explain what you have done in the code so that I can configure the button accordingly?

Comment: @HardikAswal updated the answer. You need to use `isShown(x)` instead of `showMe` now.